# What does the Green and Red mark indicate in the Git file directory?

Tags: git, github

When I run electron, the files which are linked gets some sort of mark with red and green. Can anyone help me out what do they indicate or what does that mean?
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhXff.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Niketh, That green and red mark is not from electron as i see.

Its there because of git.

Green shows file is in git repository and committed with latest changes.
Red shows file is in git repository but latest changes has not been committed. If you will hit git commit command only red marked file will be select to commit.